# Perl Regex Match Occurrence of Single Colon

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to regex match patterns with the following criteria:

I want to match a string that only has one single occurrence in the entire string. I then want to capture the portion before the single colon.

Examples of valid strings:

```
JohnP: random text here
BobF::student: random text here (this is valid because there's only ONE occurrence of a single colon. the other is a double colon)
Paris: random text here::student (valid for the same reason as above)
```

Examples of invalid strings:

```
JohnP: student: random text here
BobF::student: random text here: more
```

I have no idea how to do a regex match like this. In the case of the valid strings, the group i want to return is:

```
JohnP
BobF::student
Paris
```

I would appreciate the help! I have tried `$string =~ ^[^:]+:\s*` but that only matches up to the first colon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^((?:::|[^:])*+):(?!.*(?<!:):(?!:))
```

It looks for some number of pairs of colons or non-colon characters followed by a colon, using a possessive quantifier (`*+`) to prevent matching part-way through a double-colon in a string such as `Bill:: xyz`. Those characters are captured in group 1. A negative lookahead assertion is then  used to check that there are no more single colons in the string.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gpWdF8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps regular expression can be in form: match until `:` not preceded with `:` and not followed with `:`.

Note: code written in *shorted* form

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/^(.+)(?<!:):(?!:)/;

/$re/ && say $1 for <DATA>;

__DATA__
JohnP: random text here
BobF::student: random text here (this is valid because there's only ONE occurrence of a single colon. the other is a double colon)
Paris: random text here::student (valid for the same reason as above)
```

Output

```
JohnP
BobF::student
Paris
```